# intervlan within Virtual OS

Tags: virtual-machines

Is it accepted procedure to create a dedicated VLAN for internal communication of my virtual OS?

this hardware is connected to a switch, when an *OS* needs a specific service from another *OS* inside the same machine, traffic need not to be routed outside the hardware. It will just go directly to the VLAN dedicated to interconnect the internal OS'

I just want to know and learn if this can affect any performance issue or this could somehow mess some protocols and routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on procedures, while VLANs are not necessary for that sort of functionality, they can make things cleaner, and much simpler to administer. The only possible performance issue is the nearly negligible overhead it adds to packet size and processing. As it's a level 2 addition, it should not interfere with routing or protocols, unless you are using broadcast packets, as VLANs are often to host separate subnets, so you might have to work a bit to get something like UDP broadcasts (heartbeats in HA) going between VLANs. Otherwise it would be just like having separate networks, nothing beyond routes are necessary to connect them.

Comment: but would you still recommend it?

Comment: I would, if you want proper separation between virtual servers. I have always used VLANs, as it keeps traffic with multiple subnets cleaner, and easier to understand.